# How to retrieve data using id or pk in django

Tags: python, django, slug

I am working on a project but after trying multiple ways I still couldn't find the solution. I need to get the current room on the page so that user can leave room, I am aware that it has to do with making queries or using pk,id. (My 1st question ever, sorry if it is not correct way to ask).

This is the code from Views.py:

```
def leave_room(request, room):
    room = request.GET['room.pk']
    room_details = Room.objects.get(name=room)
    messages = Messages.objects.filter(room=room_details.pk)
    membership = RoomMember.objects.filter(user=request.user, room=messages)
    membership.delete()
    return redirect("/")
```

urls.py:

```
path("leave/<int:pk>/join/", views.leave_room, name="leave_room"),
```

html:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'leave_room' pk=room.pk %}">Leave Room</a>
```

models.py:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='room_creator')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="RoomMember")
    
    
class RoomMember(models.Model):
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='memberships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        
class Messages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Do you try `Room.objects.get(pk=room)`?

Comment: Can you share the `Room`, `Messages` and `RoomMember` models`?

Comment: I edited my original post and included models there :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a parameter `<int:pk>` the primary key of the room is passed through the `pk` parameter. This thus means that `leave_room` should be implemented as:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
@login_required
def leave_room(request, pk):
    nitems, __ = RoomMember.objects.filter(
        user=request.user, room_id=pk
    ).delete()
    if not nitems:
        raise Http404
    else:
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
```

The removal link is thus a mini form to make a POST request to the view:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'leave_room' pk=room.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Leave Room</button>
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).